Firebase Analytics logEvent run asynchronously
I am implementing Firebase analytics in my web app. So I use
export function LogAnalyticsEvent(
  eventName: string,
  eventParams?: {
    page_title?: string;
    page_location?: string;
    page_path?: string;
    [key: string]: any;
  }
) {
  const analytics = getFirebaseAnalytics();
  logEvent(analytics, eventName, eventParams);
}

And it works perfectly for page views etc. But I am implementing a redirect page like "You are leaving this site" and whenever the user is redirected I want to log an event that counts the redirect:
 const [redirecting, setRedirecting] = useState(false);
 const handleRedirect = async () => {
    setRedirecting(true);
    if (url) {
      try {
        const targetUrl = new URL(url); // Revalidate URL before redirectx
        // Log the redirect event
        LogAnalyticsEvent("redirect_to_url", {
          url: targetUrl.href,
          domain: targetUrl.hostname,
        });
        window.location.assign(targetUrl.href);
        setRedirecting(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error:", e);
        setRedirecting(false);
      }
    }
  }; 

The event doesn't get logged when the user is redirected because there isn't enough time for the request to complete. I tried using setTimeout but it didn't work in some cases, like slow internet. Is there a way for me to use an async logEvent? Or what are some fixes for this problem?


Is there a way for me to use an async logEvent?

No.  All of the Firebase APIs are asynchronous on all client platforms.  Anything else would risk causing the web site to lock up the browser potentially indefinitely, which is a terrible user experience. In fact, I don't even think there are any synchronous network APIs offered by JavaScript for use in a browser for this very reason.
If you want to log something at the same time as a redirect, your only viable option here is to perform the log on the page after the redirect, perhaps storing or passing some state locally to be handled later.
